# for loop that indicates the end of id doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I want to run through a for loop to indicate the end of the id that needs to be triggered. Because this is dynamically built in vb.net I can't get access to it easily, so I'm trying it this way.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_select1_" + i).change(function() {
        if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_select1_" + i).val() == "0") {
            //window.alert('yes dit werkt');
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_emailinput1_" + i).hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_emailinput1_" + i).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: WHat output you need here?

Comment: There are for example 3 similar select buttons and when one of them is selected another input field (that belongs to that specifis selectbutton) should show (or hide if its deselected). So the "i" at the end of the id makes their id's unique.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a tad vague, can you elaborate?   Your issue is down to modified closures.  The `change` event doesn't fire until the loop has exited, at which time the variable `i` is no longer the expected value in the loop.

Comment: Try this: `for (loopi = 0; loopi < 4; loopi++) { var i=loopi; ` (and keep the rest the same (ie use `+ i` where you have, only use `loop` in the `for` and in the first `var i=loopi`))

Comment: Your first comment already helped me out. I put the for loop underneath the change event trigger, and instead of trigger that change event on different id's, I triggered it on a class I gave it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not to familiar with the subject but the "i" variable might be shared between all event. This mean that when the event is called, i will always be 4.